# Como hacer una consulta entre dos campos

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenas estoy mostrando las horas en mi página desde las 06:00 hasta las 17:00 este rango de fechas varía puede ser desde 08:00 hasta 11:00 estos rango van aumentando de a 15 minutos ejemplo:

08:00 -08:15
08:15-08:30

en mi tabla ServicioDisponibilidad tengo el campo HoraPar que es el que tengo que mostrar dependiendo de la hora del campo HoraDesde y HoraHasta estos campos son dinámicos pueden variar entonces no los puedo colocar directamente en la consulta, el resultado que espero es el siguiente:

08:00 - 08:15   - Horapar =03:00
13:00 - 013:15   - Horapar =20:00

La consulta que estoy tratando de hacer es la siguiente pero no me funciona alguna ayuda de como lo puedo hacer abajo dejo la imagen de la tabla

```
Select HoraDesde,HoraPar,IDDisponibilidad 
From ServicioDisponibilidad 
Where IDDisponibilidad='4075' and IDServicio = '31' and IDDia like '%4|%' and IDServicioElemento like '%|%' AND HoraDesde BETWEEN '06:40' AND '06:50 ' AND Activo='S'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La pregunta está difícil de entender... ¿Cómo se calcula o de dónde viene `HoraPar`? Es un dato introducido directamente en la Base de datos o es calculado a partir de `HoraDesde` y `HoraHasta`?

Comment: @VFG si te fija en la imagen HoraPar tiene el valor 03:00:00 y 20:00:00. Lo mas Sensato es que lo haya introducido a mano... porque no creo que haya introducido un now, lo que si me gustaría saber onde esta ``IDServicioElemento``, ``IDServicio ``, ``IDDia`` y ``Activo`` Porque eso datos no esta en la imagen... Porque no somos adivino, por eso te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta y añadas todos los datos de tu tabla...

Comment: Si pones un ejemplo de lo que esperas obtener a partir de los datos de una fila quizá se pueda entender la pregunta, pues tu planteamiento es muy confuso. Por otra parte, intuyo que el problema que estás teniendo aquí es debido a un mal diseño de datos. Esto por ejemplo es muy sospechoso: `IDDia like '%4|%'`, parecería que quieres guardar varios datos en la misma fila ¿?, además, ¿estarías guardando días por un lado y horas por otro? ¿Has pensado en trabajar con columnas `DATETIME`?